# Authorization is Redis: ACL

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Since Redis supports ACL from v6.How can we achieve authorization at the key pattern? We want to implement a system in which multiple services have their own key pattern and we don't want any service can read other service's data.

For example:

| Service Name | Keys Pattern |
| --- | --- |
| Service A | Service_A_::_ |
| Service B | Service_B_::_ |

so that service A can't read data of service B and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Design the key as

**{namespace}:{object type}:{identifier}:{optional name}**.

Example :

**public:users:{1234}:purchase**

Key patterns restrictions can be done using **~:***.
Example ~public:* when used with setuser will allow user to have access to public namespaces. More information available at https://redis.io/topics/acl

Answer (score 0):

ACLs can be implemented differently in different systems. I'll break down the elements of the command to provide a general explanation:

ACL SETUSER <username> on ><password> ~Service_A_::_* +@all

ACL SETUSER <username> on ><password> ~Service_B_::_* +@all

ACL SETUSER : This part of the command likely specifies that you are setting or modifying ACL permissions for a user with the username specified in . It means you are configuring access control for a particular user.

on >: This part of the command might indicate that you need to authenticate yourself as a privileged user or administrator by providing the password associated with the username . The > symbol could be a placeholder for the actual password.

~Service_A_*: This appears to be a pattern or wildcard used to match multiple resources or services. It might indicate that you are applying the following permissions to all resources or services that match the pattern "Service_A_*." This part is typically used to specify which resources or services are affected by the ACL.

+all: This part of the command suggests that you are granting all permissions (read, write, execute, etc.) to the user specified in  for the resources or services that match the pattern "Service_A_*."